# receive abstract type in WebAPI as input

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, jsonserializer

I have the following WebAPI action insed a controller (example):

```
public MyAbstractClass Action1(MyAbstractClass input)
{
    return input;
}
```

the class structure is like so:

```
public class MyAbstractClass 
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class ConcreteClass1 : MyAbstractClass 
{
   public string Foo {get;set;}
}

public class ConcreteClass1 : MyAbstractClass 
{
   public string Bar {get;set;}
}
```

I wan to make a call to the WebAPI `Action1` with a JSON describing one of the concrete classes but it always returns null.

I have set my formatter like this:

```
public static void Configure(MediaTypeFormatterCollection formatters)
{
    var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
    var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;

    settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
    settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCaseExceptDictionaryKeysResolver();
}

private class CamelCaseExceptDictionaryKeysResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonDictionaryContract CreateDictionaryContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonDictionaryContract contract = base.CreateDictionaryContract(objectType);

        contract.DictionaryKeyResolver = propertyName => propertyName;

        return contract;
    }
}
```

NOTE i have a custom resolver and i have set `settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;`

so i send a post request witha JSON looking like this:

```
{
   "$type": "MyNameSpace.SubNameSpace.ConcreteClass1"
   "id":100,
   "name":"some name",
   "foo":"some value of foo..."
}
```

and yet receive `null` as the output .. meaning the sterilizer is unable to deserilize the concrete class.

what have i missed here ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

when posting the object i have set the

```
"$type": "MyNameSpace.SubNameSpace.ConcreteClass1"
```

need to set it to:

```
"$type": "MyNameSpace.SubNameSpace.ConcreteClass1, DLLName"
```

had to add `... ,DLLName` so it will be fully qualified name.